# How would I develop a library management system as web application by using Java technology

Tags: java, html, css, jakarta-ee

How should I start to develop a web application for the library management system by using the MVC design pattern?
My requirement is that an admin can manage librarians and librarians can manage books and students.
How would I start working on it? Should I create a view or controller(servlet) or model?"
I have to save admin email and password explicitly in the database or I have to give an option to admin that first register if I will give register option to admin then anyone might be the admin. Which is the better way to do it?

I have created a servlet which redirects to a JSP page in which I took one body tag. Inside the body tag I have taken two different form tags. Inside both form tags I have taken div tags, one for admin and librarian login but I'm facing a problem as I am able to give input text in admin email and password field form but in librarian form I am not able to give user input in text field what I need to do overcome from this problem.
If it is not possible to take two form tag inside one body then how I can create two login form in one Html page one for admin and librarian.
Please see the below code and help out.
    `Admin.java

        package admin;

        import java.io.IOException;

        public class Admin extends HttpServlet{
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");

        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }    }`

    `
    
    
    
    Home

```
<form action="" >

<div align="left" class="adm">
<h1>Admin Login</h1>
Email address:<input type="text" name="email"></br>
Password:<input type="password" name="pasword"></br>
<input type="button" value="Login">
</div>
</form>    
<form action="">
<div align="right">
<h2>Librarian Login</h2>
Lemail address:<input type="text" name="lemail"/></br>
password:<input type="password" name="pass"></br>
<input type="button" value="Login">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can quickly get started with Spring-Boot. It will help you set up the code quickly and without any hassles for dealing with Servlets and all.

There are manly readily available free templates for setting up admin panel(HTML and css)

You may use them directly to get started quickly with a good UI.

Hope this helps !!

Thanks,
Dhruv

Comment: I know that I can build quickly web application with spring-boot but I apply for an interview they gave me a task to do it with je22 technology if you have any idea regarding this question then answer me I will thankful for you

Comment: @siddhantsahani - I don't see a reason why you down voted my answer. I never knew you have an interview to answer. The idea was to help you in the right direction.

Comment: I haven't downvoted your answer it happened by mistake because first time using StackOverflow I apologize for that. If you can help me out at least in UI part my code in one body I am trying to take two different form tag one for admin and librarian in admin I am able to give input text but in librarian, I am not able to give any input text please see my Html code

Comment: You can use custom templates for admin panel. They have all the HTML UI code.   https://colorlib.com/wp/free-html5-admin-dashboard-templates/ . Just use them directly to build your portal.